# Java Action receiving “\r\n” for each new line in textarea field But Javascript gets only '\n'

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I want to automatically cut a string from a textarea up to 255 characters. . So that my Action gets only 255 characters.

But the problem is Javascript considers line break as one character while Java treats it as two `("\r\n")`.

So even if I limit text area string length to 255 characters by following code

```
$('textarea[name*="matterData.customFields"]').each(function () {
 if($(this).val().length>=255){
    a=$(this).val().substring(0, 254);
    $(this).val(a);
 }
```

in my action string length is always greater than 255 characters as new line is changed to `"\r\n"`

How can I remove this extra \r from jQuery itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove something that isn't there, but what you could do is add it before you check the length...

```
$('textarea[name*="matterData.customFields"]').each(function () {
     var text = $(this).val();
     text = text.replace(/\n/g, "\r\n");
     if(text.length >= 255){
        a = text.substring(0, 254);
        $(this).val(a);
     }
//...
}
```

If you find that even with the specific `"\r\n"` that java is still replacing `"\n"`, i.e. it becomes `"\r\r\n"` then you can just remove the `"\r"` again after the check and substring...

```
if(text.length >= 255){
    a = text.substring(0, 254);
    a = a.replace(/\r/g, "");
    $(this).val(a);
}
```

Comment: ok. But it means for user 2 valid characters will be removed for each line break.. :(

Comment: yeah, but if that is your requirements then that is what must happen. You could remove the `\r` on the java side of things... or you could just allow more characters if it really means so much